# how to configure that when selecting a file and press enter in project window, the cursor jump to the editor

Tags: clion

I am switching from visual studio to clion and find one thing annoying - when I select a file in a project window and press "enter", the selected file opened in the editor but, unlike in visual studio, the cursor stays in the project window and don't jump to the editor. However, if I use mouse and double-click on the selected file, the cursor jumps to the editor, same as in visual studio. I wonder if there is a way to configure "Enter" in project windows to go to editor as well.

Comment: Have you tried pressing F4 when in the Project view? It should open an Editor and transfer focus there.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks!